# Cant access MAMP server from other computers on my network

Tags: mamp

I have setup MAMP as a web testing environment on my MacBook Air on my network (its local ip address is 10.0.0.10). It operates fine on that on the MacBook Air, i.e. localhost:8888 takes me to the Apache root directory.

Now I want to do some testing from a Windows machine I have on the same network. From the windows machine I typed in the following 10.0.0.10:8888 into Firefox. It says it is connecting for ages, then sometimes after a while some content shows, but it still says it is loading.

I can't work out what is going on. I have no firewall on the MacBook Air. The https.conf file is set to listen to port 8888.

Is there anything special that I need to do with a MAMP server to be able to access it on other machines?

Comment: Maybe your mamp is only listening on 127.0.0.1:8888 (which also means localhost) but does not listen to 10.0.0.10 nor *. You may use netstat to verify this.

Comment: The https.conf file says listen 8888. There is no IP in the listen declaration.

Comment: Might not be in the declaration itself but in a virtualhost declaration. Do you know how to access the virtual host definition? Have you tried using netstat?

Comment: No I don't know how to access the virtual host def. I would be great full if you could tell me how? And no I have not tried netstat. I will try it.

Comment: What am I looking for in netstat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out. While the machine serving MAMP didn't have a firewall, the Windows machine did and obviously the port 8888 was not getting through :P.

On a side note I am working with Wordpress and needed to update the wp-config.php file and the database. localhost needed to be updated to reflect my IP address.

Answer (score 1):

For those who will land on this page in future and want to access their MAMP server by IP, add this as the very first `<VirtualHost *:80>` either with the default MacOS Apache server or with MAMP (for MAMP, put it after `NameVirtualHost *:80`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/web/root
</VirtualHost>
```

(where `/path/to/web/root` = `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` for MAMP, & = `/Library/WebServer/Documents` for the default MacOS Apache server)

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the MAMP on a network, you suppose to Allow the port in Windows Firewall to allow all connections. On a windows server instance

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your point...

Setting MAMP to use ports 80 for apache and 3306 for mySQL

I had the same issue on my machine and found this post doing a search but it didn't include how to fix it.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple hosts setup, you need to "tell" MAMP which one to redirect requests to. By default, the selection **IP** only shows `*`, which did not work for me. I needed to **select the IP address** of your computer (probably the only other possible selection).

BTW: *Modifying the VirtualHost* did not work for me very well: After making a change in MAMP, the config gets overwritten and your changes are lost.